# Solving a CSP using AC-3

Tags: algorithms, constraint-satisfaction

> Peter (P), Mary (M), Otto (O) and Dicky (D) would like to rent an apartment house. The house has three floors: G/F, 1/F, 2/F. Every floor has only one apartment. P, M, O and D must be assigned to exactly one floor. Note that more than one person can live in the same apartment. Consider the following constraints.
>
> - P and M cannot live in the same apartment.
> - D must live on a higher floor than O.
> - D must live alone.
> - If P and O live together, they must be on 1/F.
> - If P and O live separately, one of them must live on the 2/F.

How do I use AC-3 to solve this question?

I found two possible solutions: P,M,O,D = 2,0,0,1 or 1,0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

AC-3 is an algorithm for solving CSPs. In order to use it solve a question, you need to present the question as solving a CSP.

In your case, the CSP is on four variables $P,M,O,D$ ranging over $\{0,1,2\}$. The constraints are:

- $P \neq M$.
- $D > O$.
- $D \neq P$.
- $D \neq M$.
- $(P = O) \Rightarrow P = 1$.
- $(P \neq O) \Rightarrow (P = 2 \lor O = 2)$.

We can convert them into the following explicit constraints:

- $(P,M),(D,P),(D,M) \in \{(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1)\}$.
- $(D,O) \in \{(1,0),(2,0),(2,1)\}$.
- $(P,O) \in \{(0,2),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1)\}$.

You can now take any implementation of AC-3 and simply run it on these constraints.